# Change order of horizontal and vertical axis in stacked column chart?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a stacked column chart that looks like the following. The data that fills this chart looks like this:

```
hour    range            count
0       99.5+%            20
1       99-99.49%         1
1       99.5+%            19
2       99-99.49%         1
2       99.5+%            19
3       99.5+%            20
4       99.5+%            20
5       99.5+%            20
7       99.5+%            20
8       99.5+%            20
```

There are two changes that I'd like to make, but I have no idea how to do them:

- In the horizontal axis, instead of going from 0-8, go from 8-0. The more recent hours should be shown first.
- Currently, the green is being displayed first in the stacked chart and the yellows at the bottom. I would like to show the yellows at the top, and the green below the yellow. And whenever a red is shown (ie. "< 99%") that should be shown first at the top.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just right click the `Hour` field in `Category Groups and select Category Groups Properties...`. In the properties window, go to the `Sorting` tab:

[image]

Set order `Z-A` for `[Hour]`.

To get `99-99.49%` at the top, use the same approach: right click `range` field in Series group and select `Series Group Properties...`. Set `A-Z` order for `range` field.

You will get something like this:

[image]

Let me know if this helps.